# How to create a Blackberry Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, blackberry, continuous-integration

I'm have searched for a couple of days and couldn't find any solution to my problem. Is there a way to create a blackberry maven project with eclipse. I need this for continuous integration support.

The only solution that I found gives error (see answer by **Peter Butkovic**), and I can't find any way to fix them...

Thanks in advance...

**Edit**
Here is the maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.hello.bb:hellobb:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 44, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin is missing. @ line 32, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloBB 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (OS_Environment_Validation) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ hellobb ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hellobb ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ hellobb ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\hellobb-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (App_Creation_Deployment) @ hellobb ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\app-binary
      [jar] Building jar: D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\hellobb.jar
     [echo] Generating the BlackBerry App....
     [echo] Preverifying....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.081s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 27 11:25:52 FET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/110M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (App_Creation_Deployment) on project hellobb: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "preverify" (in directory "D:\work\blackberry_ws\MTest\target\app-binary"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Edit 2**

By the way. If I import the project to Eclipse, the IDE gives me this error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run 
(execution: OS_Environment_Validation, phase: validate)
```

Comment: I tried to find some error solution, but it looks like I'm the only one who ended up to face it in such a way... Solutions that I found mention other project types, not related to Blackberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should go for the solution described in: http://www.dzone.com/links/r/blackberry_app_development_using_maven_and_eclipse.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution gives errors, and I can't figure out how to fix them... I've been trying to "mavenaze" the project for a couple of days... it seams that the plugin is out of date, and nobody is maintaining it...

Comment: what errors do you get there? maybe someone can help to resolve these

Comment: maven throws an `Ant BuildException` on `goal maven-antrun-plugin`... I tried to find a solution for that to... but with no success =(

Comment: I think we need full output of maven (especially the problematic part), maybe you could add it to your question, as it's something you already tried and didn't work for you

Comment: OK, another idea to the pool, based on similar problem described in: http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/201773-eclipse-plugin-preverify-step-i-o-error-cannot-run-program-jar.html do you have preverify on your path? try to run it in command line, if it can be found, if not, please check that you have jdk installed + path correctly set up

Comment: As a matter of fact, the jdk is installed and the path is set right... =( I've been using maven for a long time... this is not an environment problem, I think...

Comment: and if you call preverify in the cli, program is started correctly?

Comment: cli = command line interface, so basically the question is if you type in the command line in the windows: preverify does it execute the command or does it complain about missing program?

Comment: OK, then I'd try to run the script once again and when it fails call exactly the same command as ant is trying to call (in the command line) and see if it works or not: preverify -classpath %RIM_JDE_HOME%/lib/net_rim_api.jar -d D:\\work\\blackberry_ws\\MTest\\target\\app-binary D:\\work\\blackberry_ws\\MTest\\target\\hellobb-1.0.jar